# How does using unsigned integers protect against integer overflow attacks?

Tags: c, c++, integer-overflow

In order to avoid problems with integer overflow in C or C++, some people have suggested to use unsigned integers. How can this protect against possible overflow attacks? Doesn't an unsigned integer still eventually overflow when incremented beyond its maximum value?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16056758/c-c-unsigned-integer-overflow errors out in a benign manner...

Comment: That post doesn't fully answer my question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Using unsigned integers does not prevent overflow. A *k*-bit variable can only represent 2<sup>*k*</sup> different values. No matter how you interpret the bits.

What you're probably referring to is the fact that *signed* integer overflow in C and C++ is [*undefined behavior*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2397984/). Which means that the C or C++ international standard does not specify any behavior of the program that triggers such overflow. Wrapping the value around or causing a run-time exception are valid options as much as opening an exploit shell. (Of course, no sane implementation would opt for the latter choice. But an exploit can become possible through further consequences.) Furthermore, the compiler is allowed to optimize based on the assumption that signed overflow does not occur and might, for example, optimize away misguided overflow checks such as `if (x + 3 < x)`.

For *unsigned* integers, on the other hand, the C and C++ international standards require that the value wraps around as if arithmetic on a *k*-bit unsigned integer was done modulo 2<sup>*k*</sup>. This means that your program can *rely* on the wraparound and use it to its benefit. (Or to shoot itself into the foot.)

Other languages like Java mandate reliable wraparound also for signed integers. (Java doesn't even have unsigned integer types.)

Speaking of security, the largest threat posed by overflow, however, is that your application logic does not *anticipate* the wraparound. And this is a problem regardless of whether you are using signed or unsigned integer types. If your application logic assumes that for a request of *n* bytes, it needs to allocate a buffer of *n* + *m* bytes (for a small constant *m* used for, say, bookkeeping) and *n* happens to be less than *m* below the maximum value your integer can hold, wraparound will cause your program to allocate a too small buffer which, in turn, will be overrun. There goes the exploit.

If you want to be secure, instead of using unsigned integer arithmetic throughout, I recommend that you do the exact opposite: Use *signed* integer arithmetic and compile with [*UbSan*](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/UndefinedBehaviorSanitizer.html). Unless your application is computation-heavy, it will have only minor run-time overhead but if the unanticipated event happens and your application overflows an integer, extra code added by the sanitizer will kill your application before an attacker can exploit it. A similar sanitizer for overflowing *unsigned* integer types cannot be written because the standard requires well-defined behavior for doing so and programs legitimately rely on it. This is actually one case where undefined behavior in the language can help make your application *more* secure.